# ios : Find a word in a (huge) dictionary/array

Tags: ios, arrays, string, dictionary

I'm trying to solve a problem that I haven't built yet, so I might be taking this the wrong way. I'm open to other possibilities if you happen to know one.

So, I'd like to simply check if a string exactly exists in a pre-made list of strings. This list could be an array or a dictionary, I'm not sure what's best.

What I'm trying to do is find a fast/optimal way to browse that array and find if my word is in there or not. I was thinking of dichotomic search but I'm not sure about it.

I had two "solutions" :

**Solution 1 :**

That array/dictionary will contain about 70.000 words, sorted alphabetically.
I browse the array from start to end until I reach my match.

This will probably be stupidly slow, specifically if my word starts with a Z.

**Solution 2 :**

I have an array `allTheWords` that contains 27 arrays "A", "B", "C", and so on.
Each array contains every word starting with that letter.

I check the first letter of my given string, and go browse my array from start to end until I reach my match.
That would be drastically faster than solution 1 so, I feel like I'm one step ahead but that it's still non optimal.

Is this viable? Do you know something better? Am I on the right path?

Note : I have zero code about this, I'm still on the paper/theoretical side of the app here, only pseudo code and little drawings.

Comment: I think the fastest way, if the array is ordered, is to do the binary search. You will find a lot of documentation, but if you don't get it, i will help you

Comment: A hashmap will give you "instant" access to a given datum, especially if they are strings. So +1 for @Fogmeister answer.

Comment: Basically, you want to use a binary search of a sorted list, a hashtable (eg, NSDictionary/NSSet), a radix tree, or just throw everything into a database and let the database software handle the search.

Comment: @Zil did my answer work? If so please remember to up vote and accept it. Otherwise let me know what didn't work and I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

In fact, you could probably just use an `NSSet`. I believe it uses a similar search to `NSDictionary` to keep the uniqueness. So you could just use the method `[wordSet containsObject:theSearchWord];`.

This **should** (but I can't find the documentation) also give a O(1) search performance and doesn't have the redundancy of the "value" in the dictionary.

**Original answer**

Hmm... if you use an `NSDictionary` like this...

```
{
    <THE WORD>: <BOOL>
}
```

i.e.

```
@{
    @"Apple": @YES,
    @"Banana": @YES,
    @"Orange": @YES
}
```

Then you can do something like this...

```
NSNumber *wordValue = wordDictionary[@"Apple"];
```

Then wordValue will either be `@YES` or `nil`.

The search times for this is `O(1)`.

If you want to list the words you can use the class method...

```
[wordDictionary enumerateObjectsAndKeys...
```

Or you can get an `NSArray` of the words...

```
NSArray *justTheWords = [wordDictionary allKeys];
```

Comment: As a tiny refinement, there's no real need to add the BOOL Value prt of the dictionary item - just finding the key is enough to illustrate the word is in the dictionary. Could use [NSNULL null] instead. I doubt it would save any memory, but seems semantically better to me. Also OP - 70K words is tiny.

Comment: One could use an NSSet -- basically a dictionary but with no associated values.

Comment: @Greycon ok, thanks for the info. Will update question (remove the last bit).